# Direct casting in foreach loop

Tags: java, arrays, foreach

I was wondering if its possible to directly cast objects within a foreach loop.

We have the following two classes were one extends the other:

```
class Book {};
class ExtendedBook extends Book {};
```

Now we have an array of Books which I want to loop through, because its a ExtendedBook search I'm sure that all Books are actually Extended Books. Is there a way to directly cast them?

```
Book [] books = bookSearch.getBooks("extendedBooks");

for (Book book: books){
   ExtendedBook eBook = (ExtendedBook) book;
   ....
}
```

This involves two steps. First looping through the books and at the second step casting them. Can one do it in one step?

What doesn't work:

```
// Directly assign it to a different type
for (ExtendedBook book : books){}

// Directly casting the array
ExtendedBooks [] eBooks = (ExtendedBooks []) books;

// Same goes for trying both in one step
for (ExtendedBook book : (ExtendedBook []) books){}
```

I know its not a real pain, but keeping the loop shorter would be nice and maybe more readable as you save a dummy variable, which is just used for casting instead of the actual action.

Comment: It appears that `books` is an array of Book not ExtendedBook. The elements of the array might be ExtendedBook, but you can only change this for each element. btw you can unbox in a loop `Long[] array = ... for(long l: array) { }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm reasonably sure you cannot cast in the loop as you would like.

Answer (score 3):

How about using Generics?

Write your getBooks signature as:

```
<B extends Book> B [] getBooks(Class<B> bookType)
```

Now, if you want to search for books of the type `ExtendedBook`, just call:

```
ExtendedBooks [] eBooks = bookSearch.getBooks(ExtendedBook.class)
```

No typecasting or other unsafe stuff needed. Nice and clean.

Of course you still have to make sure that only `ExtendedBook` only returns that kind of book, but it looks like you solved that already.

Comment: Actually I'm working with web services and have a generated client that returns the arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Think obout casting

```
ExtendedBook ex=(ExtendedBook)new Book();
```

It is accepted by compilator but JVM throws `java.lang.ClassCastException`, because that type of casting is wrong -> `Book` is not `ExtendedBook`, so there is a chance that it wont handle potential new methods added in `ExtendedBook` class.

For the same reason you can't do something like

```
ExtendedBook[] exbooksB=(ExtendedBook[]) new Book[10];
```

but can

```
Book[] booksA=new ExtendedBook[10];
ExtendedBook[] exbooks=(ExtendedBook[]) booksA;
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot because java does not support implicit conversion overloading like in C# with the [implicit operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85w54y0a.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this.

```
Iterables.filter('Your array', the type class).forEach(x -> { } }

Iterables.filter(data, JSONObject.class).forEach(x -> { 
    x.getString("something") });
```